# Why Ashrei in Selichot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, selichot

In most Ashkenazi versions of the selichot* for Elul and Yomim Noraim, the day's selichot begin with Ashrei**. This seems rather weird, especially considering that some (including Jekkisch authorities and the Gr"A) consider the recitation of Baruch Sheamar to be a berachah on reciting tehillim.

What is the earliest source for the recitation of Ashrei at the beginning of Ashkenazi selichot and what other versions, such as beginning with Adon 'Olam are attested to in Rishonim ?

*Versions consulted were the Minhag Russia (Chaba"d), Polin and Lita (Artscroll), and Anglia (Rosenfeld/Judaica Press).

**In my own rite, the Frankfurter minhog, we begin with Adon 'Olam, see R' Shimon Schuster's edition [here](https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/mm/publications/Selichos.pdf).

Comment: I thought it was basically performing the same function as Ashrei before mincha or musaf or neilah, which doesn't get a bracha.

Comment: Have you checked *Beurei Hatefilah* site? I vaguely recall that there is some article explaining the history and reasoning behind Ashrei.

Comment: @Heshy, By ne'ilah, the recitation is the third Ashrei of the day, taking the place of minchah, as nothing is said before petichah

Answer (score 5):

The Levush explains in his commentary on Orach Chayim 581 (page 204 in the PDF [linked here](http://hebrewbooks.org/9223)) why the *selichos* service concludes with *kaddish shalem*, which is normally reserved for after *shmoneh esrei*.

> אע״ג שבכל ימות השנה א״א תתקבל אלא אחר תפלת י״ח שכן הוא משמעות לשון צלותהן שפירושו תפלה וסתם תפלה ר״ל תפילת י״ח שאני סדר הסליחות שנתקנו כולם על סדר התפלה של כל היום כי **הפסוקים שקודם דסליחות הם כנגד פסוקי דזמרה** והסליחות עם הי״ג מדות שאומרים בין כל אחת וא״ הם במקום תפלת י״ח שעקר התפלה הוא י״ג מדות. ואח״כ נופלין על פניהם כמו אחר כל התפילות ומסיימין ואנחנו לא נדע לכך אומרים אחריהם קדיש שלם עם תתקבל כמו אחר גמר כל התפלות השנה.‏
>
> Even though the rest of the year we do not say "*tiskabel*" except after *shmoneh esrei* since the word "*tzelosehon*" means "prayer" and unspecified usage of the word "prayer" means *shmoneh esrei*, the order of *selichos* is different because it is established according to the order of the *tefilah* of every day. **The verses before *selichos* are in place of *pesukei dezimra*** and the *selichos* themselves with the 13 attributes of God which we say between each one are in place of *shmoneh esrei*. And afterwards we fall on our faces (*tachanun*) like after all other prayers and we finish with *va-anachnu lo nedah*; therefore we say afterwards *kadish shalem* with *tiskabel* like after all other *tefilos* of the year.

(my own translation)

In summary, the *selichos* service mimics the regular order of *tefilah*.

The [Lekutei Maharich](https://beureihatefila.com/files/Selichot_3.pdf) elaborates on the Levush. He explains the reason for saying *ashrei* at the beginning of *selichos* according to the reasoning of the Levush. Because the *pesukim* at the beginning of the *selichos* service are like the *pesukei dezimra* of *selichos* (so to speak), we say *ashrei* because *ashrei* is the main piece of *pesukei dezimra*.

Comment: If everything that is a form of prayer has to begin with ashrey, why don't we say it before the evening prayer?

Comment: I will refrain from voting until a new revision, but currently this is a -1, for lacking sources and being more of a comment than a true answer

Comment: @Daniel, I figured, but I'd also seen an earlier edit, so I wanted to leave constructive feedback, rather than a downvote

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ba I assume the Levush excludes maariv because it is considered a _reshus_ and therefore somewhat less significant than the other _tefilos_.

Comment: @Daniel It seems more as if he's comparing selichot to the morning prayer than to prayer in general

Comment: @ba maybe, but he doesn't say that specifically and mincha follows the same pattern. One might say the selichos service _most_ resembles mincha: ashrei, kaddish, tefilah, tachanun, kaddish. No shema, no second ashrei, etc.

Comment: I found a citing of Likutei Maharich on beurei Hatefilah. I have updated your answer to include a link to the entire article. If incorrect, or needs further editing, contact me. Nice research and answer! Shanah Tovah.

Comment: @danf excellent. Thank you